# Closing Angular-ui Tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-tabset

Below is the implementation of tabs using Angular UI-bootstrap . I would like to include some feature to close the opened tabs. Is there a way we can do it.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a [collapse](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse)?
How would you like your site to react, exactly? Otherwise you would have to write your own directive.

Here's an example:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
    <hr>
    <div uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
        <div class="well well-lg">**your tabs inside of this**</div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

example.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});
```

Comment: I'd argue that the OP hasn't told us yet what he really intends to do - the link is also the same as in the question. But i'll update the post.